# Go struct with computed key

Tags: http, post, go, struct, types

How can I create a `struct` for the following data structure in Go?

```
{
    "description": String,
    "public":      Boolean,
    "files": {
        "some_filename.txt": {
            "contents": String
        }
    }
}
```

I have started with the following:

```
type File struct {
    // stuck here?
}

type Payload struct {
    Description string
    Public      bool
    Files       File
}
```

Any help with using this for a HTTP post request would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go is not dynamically typed. Redesign. For the real case where something like this is needed: Take a look at package reflect.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a map when the key is not known a compile time:

```
type File struct {
    Contents string
}

type Payload struct {
    Description string
    Public      bool
    Files       map[string]*File
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9KNvHToXG3